# How to validate a file input in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I use built-in "file" validation rule, which [says](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-file) that a field under validation must be a successfully uploaded file.

When I upload any file I get this error of validation:

> The file must be a file

A type attribute of an input element is set to 'file':

```
<input type="file" name="file">
```

My validation code is:

```
$request->validate([
     'file' => 'required|file',
  ]);
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have multipart form data attribute on your form?

Comment: @TheFallen you are right, I forgot to define enctype. Thanks